# Split string into different labels

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to split a string into words and then putting each word on a different label.
I found here a code that can split and print each word:

```
my_phrase="The split method returns a list of the words in the string"
my_split_words = my_phrase.split() 
for each_word in my_split_words:
   print each_word
```

But how to make a loop for instead of printing, generating labels?

I'm using Python 2.7 with Kivy for the GUI. Thanks in advance!

Sorry if my formatting is wrong, first post here :)

**Edit 1:**

My code looks like this right now:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        l = [Label(text=word) for word in "The split method returns a list of the words in the string".split()]

        f.add_widget(s)
        s.add_widget(l)
        b.add_widget(f)
        return b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

After @Hugh Bothwell answer I tried to replace the old L label for the multiple labels generated on the split, but it didn't work :T

**Edit2:**
Now my code is working fine, thanks everyone. 
It takes the input from the user, then split the string into scatter labels.
It is a little messy, but it will do the job!

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        ti = TextInput(font_size=30,
                      size_hint_y=None,
                      height=50,
                      text='default')
        b = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        f = FloatLayout()

        def SplitIntoLabels(*args):
            f.clear_widgets()
            for word in new_list:
                s = Scatter(size_hint_x=None, size_hint_y=None, do_rotation=False)
                l = Label(text=word, font_size=50)
                s.add_widget(l)
                f.add_widget(s)
                s.size=l.size

        ti.bind(text=SplitIntoLabels)

        b.add_widget(ti)
        b.add_widget(f)

        return b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `labels`?

Comment: If you mean GUI label, you need to specify which GUI toolkit you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Kivy, forgot to mention. I'll try to put each label inside the Scatter Widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run `s.add_widget(l)`, but `l` is not a widget, it is a list...so this clearly won't work.

You instead want to do something like

```
for widget in l:
    s.add_widget(widget)
```

Also, when you say 'but it didn't work', it is normally useful to say *how* it didn't work, possibly along with the traceback. In this case, you should probably get a `WidgetException` including some text about the problem, which should help you debug it. Or maybe there's also another error that I wouldn't have missed with more information.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works the way I realized.
But the Scatter behaves in a way different from my initial understanding, all the labels are overlapping together in the same scatter, and it's not possible to move them separately.
I think that I need to make the loop to generate a new scatter with a new label inside `for each word.for word in t.split(): f.add_widget(s) s.add_widget(Label(text=word))` but this way I receive an Attribute Error: "NoneType" object has no attribute "bind".
Can you help me, if it is not too much to ask?

Comment: I don't follow what your new code is, could you add it to your original post?

Comment: It is working now, added the code on the original post. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label

my_phrase = "The split method returns a list of the words in the string"

labels = [Label(text=word) for word in my_phrase.split()]
```

**Edit:**

```
for lab in labels:
    s.add_widget(lab)
```

or, more directly,

```
for word in my_phrase.split():
    s.add_widget(Label(text=word))
```

Comment: I tried to replace in my code (in a dumb way) the old label with your idea, of course it didn't work. Do you know what do I need to change? Thanks for your answer!